# Uniform convergence polynomials in unit disc using maximum modulus principle.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a set of (complex) polynomials such that 
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n(z) =1$$,
for all $z$ on the unit circle $C(0,1)$ (uniformly). How to show that this also holds (using the maximum modulus principle) that on the unit disc $D(0,1)$?

Approach: I've no idea how to start. I don't see in particular how I can use the max mod principle in this problem, so any hints/solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the maximum modulus principle says that a non constant holomorphic function (in a region) cannot attain it's maximum in that region.

Comment: Start with recalling what the maximum modulus principle says.

Comment: This may help: It's the same as showing $|p_n(z)-1|\to 0$ uniformly on the closed unit disc.

Comment: Do you know a version of the maximum modulus principle that mentions the boundary of the domain?

Comment: Yes it says that (with some continuity assumptions) that the maximum is attained on the boundary. So using the comment of @zhw. I can apply this to the function $p_n(z) - 1$, then the result follows immediately because the maximum is 0 on the boundary?

Comment: Bingo! Well, the maximum isn't necessarily $0$, but it tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ by assumption.

Comment: Okay yes indeed, I got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completenes of the answer data base:

If $p_n(z)$ converges uniformly to $1$ on the unit circle $S^1 \subset \Bbb C$, then for any real $\epsilon > 0$ we have a positive integer $N$ such that $m >  N$ implies $\vert p_m(z) - 1 \vert  < \epsilon$ on $S^1$.   But $p_m (z) - 1$ is holomorphic in $D(0, 1)$ for all $m$, and hence, by the maximum modulus principle, $\vert p_m(z) - 1 \vert$ takes is greatest values on $S^1$.   Hence,

$\vert p_m(z) - 1\vert_{D(0, 1)} \le \vert p_m(z) - 1 \vert_{S^1} < \epsilon \tag{1}$

for all $m > N$, whence $p_n(z) \to 1$ uniformly on $D(0, 1)$.